# Ошибка при сборке проекта Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, swift

получаю ошибку при сборке

```
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Подробности

> Build/Intermediates.noindex/project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/project.build/all-product-headers.yaml
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Intermediates.noindex/project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/project.build/project-project-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire/Alamofire.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DLRadioButton/DLRadioButton.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FacebookCore/FacebookCore.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FacebookLogin/FacebookLogin.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FacebookShare/FacebookShare.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstanceID/FirebaseInstanceID.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReachabilitySwift/Reachability.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SDWebImage/SDWebImage.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Stripe/Stripe.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftMaskTextfield/SwiftMaskTextfield.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftValidator/SwiftValidator.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TDBadgedCell/TDBadgedCell.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPhoneNumber-iOS/libPhoneNumber_iOS.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb/nanopb.framework/Headers
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/project_customer_ios/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/project_customer_ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/project_customer_ios/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Intermediates.noindex/project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/project.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Intermediates.noindex/project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/project.build/DerivedSources/x86_64
>   -Xcc -I/Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Intermediates.noindex/project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/project.build/DerivedSources
>   -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DPB_FIELD_32BIT=1 -Xcc -DPB_NO_PACKED_STRUCTS=1 -Xcc -DPB_ENABLE_MALLOC=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Intermediates.noindex/project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/project.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/project-Swift.h
>   -import-objc-header /Users/constantine/project_customer_ios/project/Extensions/project-Bridging-Header.h
>   -pch-output-dir /Users/constantine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-eaoghxavuotxoggjlgyumdpqttot/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders
>   -working-directory /Users/constantine/project_customer_ios

проект обновлялся до меня на swift 5 и обновлялись pods

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй следующее:

- Закрой и открой заново XCode
- Очисти проект
- Запусти `pod install --repo-update`

В 90% случаев один из этих пунктов помогает.